# Find probability of skewed distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, skew

I have a variable X with summary given below.  Looking at distribution it seems like skewed normal distribution. I wonder how can I find p-value associated with each value of variable X in R?

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.5   318.3   399.9   367.1   447.4   500.0
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like more of a statistics question than a programming one, so it would be better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. But the question is also pretty unclear, I cannot follow what the p-values you are asking for are supposed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your plot, I assume you have some sequence of numbers called `averageRank`, for which you tried to fit a kernel density estimator using `density.default()`.

Essentially you have an estimate of your probability density function (output of `density.default()`). Your question states:

> I wonder how can I find p-value associated with each value of variable X in R?

Which is what `density.default()` gives to you indirectly, except only for 512 equidistant points, instead of something continuous. You could find, for a specific value `x` the closest value outputted by `density.default()` and the corresponding `y`:

```
# Create some random data:
set.seed(123)
averageRank <- rnorm(100, mean = 300, sd = 75)
x           <- 250

kde       <- density.default(averageRank)
closeness <- abs(kde$x - x)
kde$y[which(closeness == min(closeness))]
# [1] 0.004370022    # is P(X = 250)
```

However, from the way you posed your question I get the feeling you are searching for the cumulative distribution function:

```
sum(kde$y[1:which(closeness == min(closeness))]/sum(kde$y)
# [1] 0.2138626     # is P(X < 250)
```